# How do I find compatible coax connectors if I don't know the type of coax?

Tags: connector, identification, component-selection, coax

I have some small diameter coaxial cable, which we use in harsh environments.  I want to buy connectors for it. Most suppliers list thousands of connectors by cable designation, so finding compatible connectors can be a pain if you don't know the number.

The layup of the cable is:

- Inner conductor: 0.2mm/0.008" diameter stranded copper
- Insulation: PTFE or FEP, 0.4mm/0.016"
- Shield: braided copper, 12x100um wires
- Jacket: PTFE or FEP, 1mm/0.04"

Anyone know what RG number, or Belden number I should select on my supplier's website?  If anyone can post a link to a huge chart of coax designations and diameters, even better.

Comment: Is it white? Does it have anything printed on the cable?

Comment: Just use any connector that fits size, impedance and bandwidth

Comment: @Mast both insulation and jacket are clear and colourless, no printing.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yes. Most suppliers (RS and Farnell anyway) stock thousands of connectors and list them by compatible cable - so I'm looking for a quicker way than clicking every one in turn and looking at the dimensions in the datasheet.

Comment: Just buy some cable for which connectors are available. It'll save a lot of time.

Comment: @LeonHeller The harsh environment is a bit of a sticking point, but if you can recommend another type of coax cable rated for use at -270C/-450F,  40Tesla, and with a 4mm bend radius I'm all ears...

Comment: If you don't know what cable you have, how do you know it is rated for a harsh environment?

Comment: @Barry It's sold by a company specifically for cryogenic use (at  abut £15/foot!). They don't give a designation, so I don't know if it corresponds exactly to a standard type of coax, but it doesn't matter much.  If there is a similar standard coax I can use that to narrow down my search.

Comment: Interesting specs. Just curious, if you can disclose that, are you working with some kind of NMR device?

Comment: @JackB At £15/foot I would think the supplier would be happy to tell you what connectors are suitable, and maybe even sell you some.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Can't really give details I'm afraid

Comment: @AndrewMorton You'd think so, but they aren't getting back to me.  To be fair, we use very short lengths in our products, so we don't buy many feet per year.

Comment: @JackB If the connector has to work at high frequencies, say >30 GHz, then your choice of connectors will be limited. If the connector has to fit in a small space, there may be more limitations.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not looking for specific connectors (I know there's some MMCX that work) I'm looking for a way of searching for connectors.  So if a customer wants BNC, or SMA, or SMB... on the end, I can find them.  But as it happens it's low frequency (<1MHz), we just need shielding against stray capacitance.

Comment: What type of equipment will you be using with this cable? It seems to me that would help narrow down and dictate the connector type.

Answer (score 1):

Look through a table of RG type specifications and find the closest match you can for inner and outer diameters, also matching the characteristic impedance. Then search for connectors that fit that RG type.

Be warned that the RG specifications were developed a long time ago and AFAIK there's no new RG types being introduced since many years ago. So microminiature cable types may not be covered by any RG type. Which will put you right back where you started, having to check each connector datasheet or a selection guide for the range of i.d. and o.d. they accept.

Comment: I've been having a go at this, but the smallest RG types I've found are at least 2mm. If you know of an authoritative or complete list, that would be helpful.

Comment: @JackB, I'd look in the catalogs of the big cable manufacuturers (Belden, Alpha, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Old question I know.

I'm 99.9% sure that the cable in question is Lakeshore Cryotonics [Type SC](https://www.lakeshore.com/products/categories/specification/temperature-products/cryogenic-accessories/cryogenic-cable) coaxial cable.  It matches the various properties and it's made for the deep freeze.

But looks like they only sell pre-made cables with either BNC or SMA connectors.

Note: There is a 1.6mm coaxial cable that goes by the name micro-coax.  But while the inner conductor is the right size, the sizes of the insulation and the jacket are more or less swapped. It is also 75 ohm.

Comment: It is indeed that stuff, we also use a lot of the SS type. We never found any BNC/SMA/SMB connectors for it, but MMCX designed for "H+S .047 flexible" fit pretty well. We settled for always fitting those, and sending out adapters as necessary.

Comment: I was not expecting a reply 4 years later, but no one had actually answered  itso.  If you go look at some of their actually systems(where they are taking various measurements), you can find the pre-made cables for use with the systems.  The thing is, 1.60 mm seems to be an oddball.  From looking at the other cryo suppliers .80 and 1.80 are far more common as are the connectors.  Something to look into unless you have to have that specific diameter.